# Matplotlib: Problem when displaying time on y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, dateformatter

When running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
from itertools import product

Time = [f'2017-03-13 {H}:{M}:{S}' for H, M, S in list(product([('0' + str(x))[-2:] for x in range(0, 24)],
                                                              [('0' + str(x))[-2:] for x in range(0, 60)],
                                                              [('0' + str(x))[-2:] for x in range(0, 60)]))]
Speed = list(130*np.random.rand(len(Time)))
Kilometer = list(50*np.random.rand(len(Time)))
N130317 = pd.DataFrame({'Time':Time, 'Speed':Speed, 'Kilometer':Kilometer})

N130317['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(N130317['Time'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

marker_size = 1  # sets size of dots
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('plasma_r') #sets colour scheme
plt.scatter(N130317['Kilometer'], N130317['Time'], marker_size, c=N130317['Speed'], cmap=cm)
ax=plt.gca()
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.title("NDW 13-03-17")
plt.xlabel("Kilometer")
plt.ylabel("Time")
plt.colorbar().set_label("Speed", labelpad=+1) #Makes a legend
plt.show()
```

- I get a graph that looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this (made by another user):

[image]

Does anyone know the reason for this problem?

[Matplotlib: Automatically displaying time column as 2 hour ticks on y axis in scatterplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289031/matplotlib-automatically-displaying-time-column-as-2-hour-ticks-on-y-axis-in-sc/62289737#62289737) - previous question that I got the solution from.

I same problem occurs before and after I have updated conda and all the packages.

Comment: Your code works pretty well and gives the second picture on my system.

Comment: It gives the first one on my system. Incredibly frustrating.

Comment: My coworker also gets the first one in his system.

Comment: I saw that you are using `plt.scatter` but formatting the datetime in hour minutes using `ax`. Try creating a `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. Then use `ax.scatter` to plot the graph

Comment: Can you show how you would change the code?

Comment: I did not try but make these changes and see if it helps.
`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`
`marker_size = 1  # sets size of dots`
`cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('plasma_r')` 
`ax.scatter(N130317['Kilometer'], N130317['Time'], marker_size, c=N130317['Speed'], cmap=cm)`
`ax=plt.gca()`
`xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`
`ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)`

Comment: Didn't help but I found the solution

Comment: See below the code that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Replace your code with the code below. It gave me the right heatmap. It is because of the way matplotlib format the datetime. Please see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090383/plotting-unix-timestamps-in-matplotlib)

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
marker_size = 1  # sets size of dots
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('plasma_r') #sets colour scheme
ax.scatter(N130317['Kilometer'], mdates.datestr2num(N130317['Time'].astype('str')), marker_size, c=N130317['Speed'], cmap=cm)
    ax=plt.gca()

xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting:

```
plt.ylim(N130317['Time'][0], N130317['Time'][N130317.index[-1]])
```

After the scatter line solved it.